# Couldnot start the mysql Deamon : mysql.sock is missing

Tags: mysql, mysql.sock

```
service mysqld start
```

> mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Can any one help me out on this error?

Answer (score 0):

check the my.cnf file (for MySQL - either /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf) - comment out the basedir flag with hashtags (#basedir=/var/lib) and restart the server.